# R: Need y label to be two lines

Tags: r, plot, label, expression

I have a y label which is supposed to say 
"Abundance of *A. stutchburyi*
(# individuals / 0.50m^2)" where # individuals.... is supposed to be the second line

The problem is, I can't make it work since I'm mixing different fonts (normal and italics). Usually I use \n but that does not work within an expression..

Here is my code, which only gives me the y label on one line:

```
tsaplot <- barplot(tsa$No, beside = TRUE,
                   xlab = "Size groups (mm)",
                   ylab = expression(atop(paste("Abundance of",italic("A. stutchburyi"),"(# individuals / 0.50m^2)"))),
                   cex.axis = 1.4, density = 50, font.lab = 2, font.axis = 2, cex.lab = .9, col = "black",
                   names.arg = c("0-2.0","2.1-4.0","4.1-6.0","6.1-8.0","8.1-10.0","10.1-12.0","12.1-14.0","14.1-16.0","16.1-18.0","18.1-20.0",">20.1"),
                   ylim = c(0,100), xpd = FALSE)
```

Comment: We would need `tsa` for a reproducible example. Also, neither R/RStudio nor StackOverflow charges more for spaces & newlines. No need to make code look like minimized javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a misplacement of bracket:

```
tl <- bquote(atop(paste("Abundance of ",italic("A. stutchburyi")),"(# individuals / 0.50"*m^2 ~ ")"))

par(mar = c(5.1, 6.1, 4.1, 2.1))
plot(1, 1, t = "n", ylab = tl)
text(1, 1, tl)
```

[image]

With `barplot`:

```
par(mar = c(5.1, 6.1, 4.1, 2.1))
barplot(VADeaths, ylab = tl)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried the code you provided, as well as the above one that was suggested, but this only places the "# individuals...." as 'power of (^)' the first part of the label...

Comment: Are you sure you aren't mixing up with Jaap's answer? My answer works well.